# How to create text as a link in the comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, hyperlinks

I want to display my text as a hyperlink in the comments. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[text](link)
```

The above code format will help you to display text as hyperlink in the comments.